# How to use Jenkins Pipeline and choose triggers for email notifications?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Before Pipeline, I used [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to define triggers for sending emails (on first failure, and when back to success).

But in the Pipeline version, I can't control the triggers, I can only "send always", or send based on current build result.

How do I send emails in pipeline based on more general triggers? (first failure, first success, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use snippet like

```
post {
    changed {
        emailext body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT', recipientProviders: [brokenTestsSuspects(), brokenBuildSuspects(), developers()], subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT'
    }
}
```

in declarative pipelines.

[Changed](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) post-condition is called when the build result is changed (i.e. of first failure and back to success). There are post-conditions like "regression" if you want more control.

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be possible at the moment with pipelines. See [this Jira ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42644).

Comment: this jira ticket is about changing list of emailed users, not the triggers from question